# Drupal: character entity in menu link title

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, character-entities

I have a menu link whose link title contains a character entity (e.g. `La Ni&ntilde;a`). However, Drupal isn't recognising the character entity and is further encoding the ampersand, so I'm ending up with `La Ni&amp;ntilde;a`. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override themable output in your theme template.php file or in a custom module.

Basicaly, the point is that the l() function isn't called with the "html" option in theme_menu_link

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7
and http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

Comment: Perfect - works like a dream. Thanks for such a quick and thorough answer.

Comment: Be aware that just adding the html option can be a security risk if other users can add menu links.

Comment: @Berdir - good point. I did mean to add a note here to the effect "That works perfectly, but I guess I need to fix the root problem". Would you recommend NOT having entities in the menu link text? I.e. use the unicode character instead?

Comment: I think so, yes. Have you tried if Drupal already converts them? Probably not but if you really want it as an character entity, you could replace them in that theme function.